# HBase - Scala - Could not initialize class ProtobufUtil

Tags: scala, hadoop, playframework, hbase, protocol-buffers

I am facing an issue when trying to run a Scala API (built with Play) which communicate with a HBase table in a Hadoop cluster.

I have a binary file which was created by the command "activator dist" and it works well on the current server.
But I need to make it run on another server and it does not work on this one. When I launch the binary, it is okay but when I try to access the web page, I get this error :

```
Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil
```

It is pretty strange because the same binary is working on the first server and in local. Java version is the same on all environments (Java 8).

Any idea appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give some more inputs of how you are running including classpath command ans so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, it seems that my linux user does not have enough rights to launch the binary the first time. I asked the administrator to launch it with the root account, which worked correctly.

After this, I was able to run the binary with no problem. Si I suspect that my account does not have permission to create some files.

Comment: Somehow it needs to create /var/log/hbase/local/jars directory no work as my log showed. Thanks !

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create local dir /var/log/hbase/local/jars, DynamicClassLoader failed to init
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.initTempDir(DynamicClassLoader.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:249)
        ... 94 common frames omitted